# Find all function satisfying equation

Tags: probability-theory, functional-equations

Let $f(t)$ be a characteristic function of some random variable $X$ we know that $\displaystyle f(t) = e^{it-4t^2} \cdot f(\frac{t}{2})$ question is to find all possible functions $f$.

I tried something taking log and got something like $g(t)-g(\frac{t}{2}) = it - 4t^2$ where $g(t) = \ln(f(t))$ and hypothesis is $g(t)$ is quadratic function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently, then $$f(t) = e^{it-4t^2}\cdot e^{i{t\over2}-4\left({t\over2}\right)^2}\cdot f\left(\frac{t}4\right)$$
By expanding $f\left(\frac t4\right)$, then $f\left(\frac t8\right)$ and so on, we get a chain of exponents which simplifies nicely, and some $f\left(\frac{t}{2^n}\right)$. Now, $f(x)$ being a *characteristic function* tells us something about its behavior at $x\to0$, doesn't it?

Comment: $\displaystyle f(t) = e^{2it-\frac{16}{3}t^2}$ right ?

Comment: Sounds about right, yeah.